# AWS::ECS::Cluster object does not support attribute CapacityProviders

Tags: troposphere

Troposphere module version: 2.6.2.

Python script:

```
import troposphere.ecs as ecs
from ecs import *
...
template.add_resource(ecs.Cluster(
    "Cluster",
    CapacityProviders=["FARGATE", "FARGATE_SPOT"]
))
...
```

Why am i getting this error when running the script that creates the template?

```
AWS::ECS::Cluster object does not support attribute CapacityProviders
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not supported in `2.6.2`. Update to `2.6.3` should solve your problem

Comment: any documentation supporting the idea?

Comment: you can reference to this line https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/a33ee4e519efe0f154cd3bc6a67f217da5d871b1/troposphere/ecs.py#L71